# Why is -1 zero fill right shift 1=2147483647 for integers in Java?

Tags: java, bit-shift

For the program below:

```
public class ZeroFillRightShift
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    int x = -1;
    int y = x>>>1;
    System.out.println("x = " + x);
    System.out.println("y = " + y);
  }
```

I get the output as follows:

```
x = -1
y = 2147483647
```

The result that I got for `-1>>>1` is 2147483647. If it’s the sign bit that has to be shifted, as I learned, the result should be 1073741824. Why is it 2147483647 then?

The following image illustrates my problem more clearly:

[image: The sample image]

Comment: -1 is not the number that has only the signbit set, that's Integer.MIN_VALUE. -1 is the number with all bits set.

Comment: That's a very well asked question.

Comment: You are forgetting that an `int` is composed of 32 bits, or 4 bytes. And 2^32 - 1 is definitely not ~2 billion. When you do a 'prepend 0 bit' right shift on 2^32 - 1, you get 2^31 - 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The unsigned right shift operator ">>>" shifts a zero into the
>   leftmost position, while the leftmost position after ">>" depends on
>   sign extension.

So, -1 is shifted right one bit with zero-extension, which means it will insert a 0 into the leftmost position.  Remember, we're dealing with [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) here:

-1 is: `11111111111111111111111111111111` or `0xFFFFFFFF` in Hex

-1 >>> 1 is `01111111111111111111111111111111` or `0x7FFFFFFF` in Hex, 
 which is 2<sup>31</sup> - 1  == 2147483647

Here's a JLS reference for [shift operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19).

You seemed to be confused about two's complement. 31 bits are used for the value and the bit farthest to the left is used for the sign.  Since you're only shifting by 1 bit, the signed bit becomes a 0, which means positive, and the result is the greatest positive number than an `int` can represent.

Perhaps another example will help.  Let's consider the following:

```
System.out.println(-2 >> 1); //prints -1
```

-2 = `11111111111111111111111111111110`

If we use a signed right shift, we get: `11111111111111111111111111111111`, which is -1. However, if we do:

```
System.out.println(-2 >>> 1); //prints 2147483647
```

since -2 = `11111111111111111111111111111110` and do an unsigned right shift, which means we shift by 1 bit with zero-extension, giving: `01111111111111111111111111111111`

Comment: [Link to official docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) is always a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

The 32-bit decimal ([two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)) value -1 is 0xFFFFFFFF in hexadecimal. If you do an unsigned right shift ( `>>>`) by one bit on that you get 0x7FFFFFFF, which is 2147483647 decimal.

Comment: My question is why it is so? Please see the image I had attached with my question. Thanks for taking time to answer!

Comment: The mistake in your image is the assumption that -1 is 0x80000001, i.e. that signed numbers are stored in a sign-magnitude format. The actual representation used is two's complement, which you can read more about in the article I linked to.

Answer (score 2):

Your confusion arises from the (very common) misconception that there is a "sign bit" in 2s-complement intergers. It isn't. The left most bit, also known as the most significand bit (MSB) actively contributes to the value of the number.

In 2s complement notation, this bit merely indicates the sign of the number. But manipulation of that bit does not simply change the sign.

Another noteworthy property of the machine internal int format is that you don't need to interpret them as signed numbers. In fact, this is exactly what you do when you use the `>>>` operator: You interpret the number as unsingned number (notwithstanding the myth that "Java does not have unsigned integers"). Hence:

```
0xffffffff >>> 1 == 4294967295 / 2
```

and this is how your result makes sense.
(Note that you can't write the above in Java source code, it will complain that the deciaml number is "out of range".)

Data types with true sign bits are IEEE floating point numbers.

Comment: Can you show an example with decimal to binary instead to hexadecimal to decimal?

Comment: Hexadeciaml is a concise notation to write binary. Just replace each `f` with `1111` and you have it binary. You should nevertheless learn to "think" in hexadecimal when you're interested in problems like that. For this, make yourself a small cheat sheet with the binary representation of all the 16 hexadeximal digits. You'll notice after a while that you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The left-most bit in signed integer values are used to indicate weather the number is positive (0) or negative (1). -1 is represented as all bits on: `11111111111111111111111111111111`. If you shift it left with `>>>`, you get `01111111111111111111111111111111` which is the highest positive number 2^31 - 1 = 2147483647