# Why is -1 right shift 1 = -1 in Java?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I came across the question ["Why is -1 zero fill right shift 1=2147483647 for integers in Java?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20439767/why-is-1-zero-fill-right-shift-1-2147483647-for-integers-in-java)

I understood the concept of zero fill right shift perfectly well from the above question's answer. But when I tried to find -1>>1, I am getting a totally complex answer which I felt difficult to understand.

```
-1 in binary form is as follows: 11111111111111111111111111111111
After flipping the bits, I got:  00000000000000000000000000000000
Upon adding 1 to it, I got:      00000000000000000000000000000001
Now shifting one position right: 00000000000000000000000000000000 
After flipping the bits, I got:  11111111111111111111111111111111
Now adding 1 to it:              00000000000000000000000000000000
```

I don't understand how -1>>1 is -1 itself, then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do a normal right-shift (i.e. using `>>`, also known as an *arithmetic* right shift, as opposed to `>>>`, which is a *logical* right shift), the number is *sign extended*.

How this works is as follows:

When we right-shift we get an empty spot in front of the number, like so:

```
 11111111111111111111111111111111
 ?1111111111111111111111111111111(1)  (right-shift it one place)
```

The last `1` is shifted out, and in comes the `?`.

Now, how we fill in the `?` is dependent on how we shift.

If we do a *logical shift* (i.e. `>>>`), we simply fill it with `0`.
If we do a *arithmetic shift* (i.e. `>>`), we fill it with the first bit from the original number, i.e. the *sign bit* (since it's `1` if the number is negative, and `0` if not). This is called sign extension.

So, in this case, `-1 >> 1` sign-extends the `1` into the `?`, leaving the original `-1`.

### Further reading:

- [Arithmetic shift on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift)
- [Logical shift on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift)

Comment: How about the case of -2>>1? I mean the result of -2 arithmetic shift 1 is getting stuck according to your logic. Please explain your answer with -2 as example too.

Comment: @AbyWang: http://ideone.com/LnvP5N - We shift the `0` off from the right hand side, and sign-extend a `1` in front, giving `-1`.

Comment: Maybe interesting to add is that thanks to sign extension a shift right operation is arithmetically a division by two for negative values as well!

Comment: ... and it always rounds down, in contrast to normal integer division, which rounds towards zero. So `-1 / 2 = -0.5` is rounded down to `-1`.

Answer (score 3):

`>>` is a 'signed right shift' operator, so it will preserve the leftmost bit.

So as `-1` (dec) is `0xb11111111111111111111111111111111` (bin), right shifting it using `>>` will preserve the `1` and the result is again `0xb11111111111111111111111111111111` (bin).

For unsigned right shift, the operator `>>>` can be used. It always fills up with zeroes (0). In your case, `-1 >>> 1` results in `0b01111111111111111111111111111111`, or `2147483647`, which is the largest possible (positive) 32 bit two's complement (and equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`).